# Best practice for dealing with shopify canonical url mess [redirects?]

Tags: seo, google-search-console, shopify, ahrefs

What is the best practice for dealing with "no internal links to canonical URLs" SEO issue. Linking to the canonical URL is not a viable solution for me so I was considering using 301 redirects to the canonical URL from any non canonical URL.

If the best practice is to 301 redirect to the canonical URL, is there a way to automate this with liquid/shopify API?

Would something like this be optimal?

`{% if template =='product' and page.url != product.url %}<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL={{ product.url }}" />{% endif %}`

or is there a better way of doing it since meta refresh is apparently looked down upon in SEO.

Comment: Why is linking to the canonical URLs infeasible?

Comment: What tool is uncovering this SEO problem for you? Is this something that Google Search Console reports, or is the problem reported in some other tool?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's reported in Ahrefs site audit as an actual issue for me, not even a warning. And it's unfeasible because the majority of non-canonical links come from Shopify generating them through collections and stuff. 

The page that I land on is the exact same project page, so I'd be linking from the product page to the product page, which makes no sense.